# Need Help in Python Variables

Tags: python

Consider Below Code(Python)

```
  k=[45,51,66,11,99,44]
  z=k
  z.reverse()
```

Here Instead of Z the variable K also Reveresed

So What I need is only child variable z need to be reversed without modifying K variable (list)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> k=[45,51,66,11,99,44]
>>> z = k[:]
>>> k.reverse()
>>> k
[44, 99, 11, 66, 51, 45]
>>> z
[45, 51, 66, 11, 99, 44]
```

This is a well known python behaviour and it has to do with its handling of references.

By doing `z=k` you're not saying "make a copy of `k` and assign it to `z`", but rather you're making both `z` and `k` point to *the same object*, or the same memory location. This has the implicit consequence that any change to `z` also affects `k` and vice versa. In other programming languages this behaviour is known as *aliasing*.

By using `z=k[:]` i'm using list slicing to explicitly create a *new copy* of `z`, and then assigning that new copy to `k`. That way, they're independent of one another and changes are not applied to both.